# Azure B2C Log out has trouble signing me IN(!)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

My Blazor server-side application uses Azure B2C authentication. Currently, I run it locally. Sign in works correctly, but when I press **Sign Out**, I get

> Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you **in**.
>
> ...
>
> The id_token_hint parameter has not been specified in the request.
> Please provide token and try again.

In my Azure app registration, I have Front-channel logout URL set to

https://localhost:44333/

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have enabled "require id token hint on logout", which protects the post_logout_redirect_uri.

In this case, you must pass a query parameter as part of the logout call to AAD B2C as follows `&id_token_hint=<id_token>`.

This is nothing to do with front channel logout url. That is invoked when you are signed into to 2 apps, signing out from app1, will call front channel logout url of app2 for single logout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I unchecked "require id token hint on logout". Now I am able to log out, and return to the login screen. However, when I enter credentials, login does not happen. The same login page is reloaded (it does work if I just close the application and start it again). Also, could you please tell where exactly I should use that query parameter? Thanks!

Comment: Also, where should I take the id_token?